# Determine the number of NA values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to count the number of `NA` values in a data frame column. Say my data frame is called `df`, and the name of the column I am considering is `col`. The way I have come up with is following:

```
sapply(df$col, function(x) sum(length(which(is.na(x)))))
```

Is this a good/most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 436):

You're over-thinking the problem:

```
sum(is.na(df$col))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. To expand this a little bit. In counting amount of arbitrary `value`, other than `NA` is writing a boolean function  `is.value` and then using `sum(is.value(df$col))` the way to go or is there a more concise direct syntax for this?

Comment: Was too quick to ask. `sum(df$col==value,na.rm=FALSE)` does the trick.

Comment: @user3274289: although you'll usually want `na.rm=TRUE`, because otherwise if `df$col` contains NAs, `sum` will return `NA`.

Comment: Sometimes I think I am over-thinking, till I got this answer...well, it's true...

Comment: sorry but this does not work for me. I get this warning Warning message:
In is.na(nom$wd) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL', and the count is just zero.

Comment: you can also count non-NA values with `sum(!is.na(df$col))`

Answer (score 102):

If you are looking for `NA` counts for each column in a dataframe then:

```
na_count <-sapply(x, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
```

should give you a list with the counts for each column.

```
na_count <- data.frame(na_count)
```

Should output the data nicely in a dataframe like:

```
----------------------
| row.names | na_count
------------------------
| column_1  | count
```

Comment: To include the row names as a column, also run `na_count$name<-rownames(na_count)`.

Comment: `na_count <-sapply(x, function(y) sum(is.na(y)))` is a shorter alternative.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( Had to change it to: 
na_count <- apply(x, function(y) sum(is.na(y)) , MARGIN = 2)

Comment: I don't think we need to use both the sum and the length function (in the first na_count assignment)? Just length should be sufficient.

Answer (score 73):

Try the `colSums` function

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,NA), y = rep(NA, 3))

colSums(is.na(df))

#x y 
#1 3
```

Comment: If you are dealing with many colums, you can reach a nicer output  with 

´ colSums(is.na(df)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() ´

or

´ as.data.frame(colSums(is.na(df))) ´

Answer (score 39):

A quick and easy Tidyverse solution to get a `NA` count for all columns is to use `summarise_all()` which I think makes a much easier to read solution than using `purrr` or `sapply`

```
library(tidyverse)
# Example data
df <- tibble(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA), 
             col2 = c(NA, NA, "a", "b"))

df %>% summarise_all(~ sum(is.na(.)))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>    col1  col2
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
```

Or using the more modern `across()` function:

```r
df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: how would I get the NAs as a single number in total?

Comment: @Ben - if you want to save the output as a separate column you need to supply the `.names` argument. This uses a glue specification, e.g.:

`df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.)), .names = "{.col}_na.count")`

will create a new column for each variable, with the number of NAs for that variable.

Answer (score 24):

If you are looking to count the number of NAs in the entire dataframe you could also use

```
sum(is.na(df))
```

Answer (score 16):

In the `summary()` output, the function also counts the `NA`s so one can use this function if one wants the sum of `NA`s in several variables.

Comment: Worth noting that the `summary` output when used on a single column is useable, while its output from an entire data frame is character and the counts are difficult to extract if you need them later.  See `c(summary(mtcars))`.

Answer (score 11):

A tidyverse way to count the number of nulls in every column of a dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

df %>%
    map_df(function(x) sum(is.na(x))) %>%
    gather(feature, num_nulls) %>%
    print(n = 100)
```

Comment: You don't even need purrr: `df %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))`

Comment: If you are lazy like me, you can write the same in @Abi K's answer in the somewhat shorter purrr syntax as: `df %>% map_df(~sum(is.na(.)))` or without dplyr as `map_df(~sum(is.na(df)))`

Comment: Best solution for me as it gives the best colnames to proceed

Answer (score 8):

This form, slightly changed from Kevin Ogoros's one:

```
na_count <-function (x) sapply(x, function(y) sum(is.na(y)))
```

returns NA counts as named int array

Comment: to get result as list: `na_count <-function (x) lapply(x, function(y) sum(is.na(y)))`

Answer (score 6):

```
sapply(name of the data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

User rrs answer is right but that only tells you the number of NA values in the particular column of the data frame that you are passing to get the number of NA values for the whole data frame try this:

```
apply(<name of dataFrame>, 2<for getting column stats>, function(x) {sum(is.na(x))})
```

This does the trick

Comment: There are some typos that make this code non-functional. Try this;  `apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
length(df$col[is.na(df$col)])
```

Answer (score 3):

I read a **csv** file from local directory. Following code works for me.

```
# to get number of which contains na
sum(is.na(df[, c(columnName)]) # to get number of na row

# to get number of which not contains na
sum(!is.na(df[, c(columnName)]) 

#here columnName is your desire column name
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for null values in each column to be printed one after the other then you can use this. Simple solution.

```
lapply(df, function(x) { length(which(is.na(x)))})
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to hute37's answer but using the `purrr` package. I think this tidyverse approach is simpler than the answer proposed by AbiK.

```
library(purrr)
map_dbl(df, ~sum(is.na(.)))
```

Note: the tilde (`~`) creates an anonymous function. And the '.' refers to the input for the anonymous function, in this case the data.frame `df`.

Comment: Nice and clean but the colname is quite messy. Do you have a nice solution to call is "count_NA"?

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `complete.cases` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(col = c(1,2,NA))
df
#>   col
#> 1   1
#> 2   2
#> 3  NA
sum(!complete.cases(df$col))
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to count number of NA or blanks in every column

```
colSums(is.na(data_set_name)|data_set_name == '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of completeness you can also use the `useNA` argument in table. For example `table(df$col, useNA="always")` will count all of non `NA` cases and the `NA` ones.