# How can I count number of NA values in dataset?

Tags: r

How can I know how many values are NA in a dataset? OR if there are any NAs and NaNs in dataset?

Comment: `anyNA`, `complete.cases`, and `na.omit` are all useful functions. Your question is not very specific and clearly off-topic.

Comment: There is not function named anyNA in R. Can you tell me how you used it?

Comment: If there is no `anyNA` in your R version, you should update R.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a basic question about using R. See advice on software-related questions in the Help Center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use r without a reproducible example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the number of NA values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027605/determine-the-number-of-na-values-in-a-column)

Answer (score 12):

This may also work fine

```
sum(is.na(df)) #  For entire dataset
```

for a particular column in a dataset

```
sum(is.na(df$col1))
```

Or to check for all the columns as mentioned by @nicola

```
colSums(is.na(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

As *@Roland* noticed there are multiple functions for finding and dealing with missing values in R (see `help("NA")` and [here](http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html)).

*Example:*

Create a fake dataset with some `NA`'s:

```
data <- matrix(1:300,,3)
data[sample(300, 40)] <- NA
```

Check if there are any missing values:

```
anyNA(data)
```

Columnwise check if there are *any* missing values:

```
apply(data, 2, anyNA)
```

Check percentages and counts of missing values in columns:

```
colMeans(is.na(data))*100
colSums(is.na(data))
```

Comment: Don't use `apply` when it's not needed. Just `colSums(is.na(data))` works.

Answer (score 0):

For a dataframe it is:

```
sum(is.na(df)
```

here df is the dataframe

where as for a particular column in the dataframe you can use:

```
sum(is.na(df$col)
```

or

```
cnt=0

for(i in df$col){
if(is.na(i)){
    cnt=cnt+1
  }
}
cnt
```

here cnt gives the no. of NA in the column

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the number of "NA" included in the each column of dataset by using R.

For a vector x

```
summary(x)
```

For a data frame df

```
summary(df)
```